# I receive the "The page object class integration.pages.login.LoginPage looks dodgy:" error when I try to run tests with AppiumDriver on Browserstack

Tags: appium, browserstack, serenity-bdd

The problem below refer to an Appium-Serenity-Cucumber-JUnit project for an app

When I run my tests locally with a WebDriver and a device connected everything works perfectly. When I change the WebDriver with AppiumDriver in order to run them on Browserstack without a physical device I receive the error.

The BasePage:

```
public class BasePage extends PageObject {
    public AppiumDriver driver;

    public BasePage(AppiumDriver appiumDriver) {
        this.driver = appiumDriver;
        PageFactory.initElements(new AppiumFieldDecorator(appiumDriver), this);
    }
}
```

Page exemple:

```
public LoginPage(AppiumDriver passedDriver) {
    super(passedDriver);
}

@iOSFindBy(xpath ="//XCUIElementTypeButton[@name=\"haveAnAccountNormalStateButton\"]")
@AndroidFindBy(id = "com.braeburn.bluelink:id/login_button")
private MobileElement loginBtn;

public void loginWith(String username, String pass){
    Waiting.visible(driver,loginBtn);
    loginBtn.click();
    Waiting.visible(driver,emailField);
    CommonTask.sendKeys(emailField, username,"email field");
    Waiting.visible(driver,passField);
    CommonTask.sendKeys(passField, pass, "pass field");
    //driver.hideKeyboard;
    signInBtn.click();
}
```

Steps exemple:

```
@Given("^User is on login page and enters valid creditentials$")
public void userIsOnLoginPageAndEntersValidCreditentials() {
    loginPage.loginWith(TestData.CORRECT_EMAIL,TestData.FIRST_PASSWORD);
}
```

Runner used:

[Runner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhdRU.jpg)

Capabilities used in Serenity:

[Capabilities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyL0U.jpg)

If anyone is able to provide a good example or any help I will be more than grateful.

Answer (score 0):

From the capabilities configuration you shared, I see that you are appending the capabilities with prefix 'appium.' and then parsing in your code. If yes, add the below capabilities to run your tests in Google Nexus 6 as per your configuration.

`appium.os_version=6.0
appium.device=Google Nexus 6
appium.real_device=true`

You can refer the sample project here:
https://github.com/browserstack/serenity-browserstack